# How to share expensive resource across multiple spock test groovy using the spock framework

Tags: java, spock

I am running a set of Spock test as integration test cases using maven surefire plugin.
I am aware that we could share the resource across fixture of a spec in a single file using the @Shared keyword.

However, is it possible to share it across different Spec file, possibly with some spec runner?
Or some annotation that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Spock uses the JUnit execution model, which doesn't envisage sharing state between test classes. A common solution is to manage shared state with a static singleton.